# How to create a side menu that the "active" item follow the page content location?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm looking to learn how to do this left menu :
http://js.devexpress.com/New/15_2/#HTML_5_JS_Core
When you scroll down the page, the "active" menu item change.

p.s.
Is there a name for this type of menu?

regards,
yaniv

Comment: The question is : How do i sync between the "content" and the "active" menu when the user scroll down ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Scroll Navigation

That is how we call these type of navigation bars. Basically you have to listen to the scroll event and calculate which element is in the viewport at the moment than you add a class to your navigation that marks the current menu element.

There is [a nice demo built in jQuery](https://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/Dxtyu/141/) but because jQuery is a thing of the past, I built one in Vanilla JS. See comments for explanations.

There are different ways to define which is the current element. In my Example it is the last one whose top line just passed the top line of the browser.

### Working demo

```js
window.onscroll = onScroll;

function onScroll() {
    var removeActiveClass = function (elements) {
        for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i) {
            elements[i].classList.remove('active');
        }
    }
    var anchors = document.querySelectorAll('#menu-center a');
    var previousRefElement = null;
    for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; ++i) {
        // Get the current element by the id from the anchor's href.
        var currentRefElement = document.getElementById(anchors[i].getAttribute('href').substring(1));
        var currentRefElementTop = currentRefElement.getBoundingClientRect().top;
        // Searching for the element whose top haven't left the top of the browser.
        if (currentRefElementTop <= 0) {
            //The browser's top line haven't reached the current element, so the previous element is the one we currently look at.
            previousRefElement = anchors[i];
            // Edge case for last element.
            if (i == anchors.length - 1) {
                removeActiveClass(anchors);
                anchors[i].classList.add("active");
            }
        } else {
            removeActiveClass(anchors);
            previousRefElement.classList.add("active");
            break;
        }
        
    }
}
```

```css
body, html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.menu {
    width: 100%;
    height: 75px;
    position: fixed;
    background-color:rgba(4, 180, 49, 0.6);
}
#menu-center {
    width: 980px;
    height: 75px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#menu-center ul {
    margin: 15px 0 0 0;
}
#menu-center ul li {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 30px 0 0;
    display: inline;
}
.active {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 50px;
}
a {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 50px;
}
.content {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
#portfolio {background-color: grey;}
#about {background-color: blue;}
#contact {background-color: red;}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
    <div id="menu-center">
        <ul>
            <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="home" class="content"></div>
<div id="portfolio" class="content"></div>
<div id="about" class="content"></div>
<div id="contact" class="content"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly menu type, it is the way how you can position objects by html.

You can use position:Abosule property to achieve this effect:
http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_position_fixed

By this given divs are "flying" above the res of the page. In your case it could be a menu.

**EDIT:**

To sync this you need to detect when given anchor is currently seen. 
It can be done by jQuery, this is sample draft of code, should explain clue of solution:

```
// list of header on page
var positions = [
    $("#anchor1").offset().top,
    $("#anchor2").offset().top,
    $("#anchor3").offset().top,
];
var menu_objects= [
    "#menu1",
    "#menu2",
    "#menu3"
];
var $w = $(window).scroll(function(){

// clear old
for(var v in menu_objects)
    $(v).css({"color","white"});

for(var i=positions.length-1;i>=0;i--)
{
    if(positions[i]>=$w.scrollTop())
    {
        $(menu_objects[i]).css({"color","red"});
        break;
    }
}
});
```

Comment: ok , but how do i sync between the "content" and the "active" menu when the user scroll down ?

Comment: You need to use jQuery, I Have added sample code for this.